# Can we use Data Access Layer in stand alone application?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am developing a `standalone java application` which is later packaged as a `jar` and will be deployed into an Enterprise application(`EAR`).

I am accessing database several times in my application using `JDBC`, in this application can I use any of the data access design patterns like `Abstract DAO`? or should I not consider including `data access layer` or any such layers in a stand alone java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of-course you can do whatever you can do with a web application. Moreover, the abstract DAO pattern is not specific to a particular set of applications.

There are couple of ways of doing this.

You can create the DAO code as a jar and include it in the class path of other proejcts which are deployed as EAR.

Answer (score 1):

Yes having a data access layer to consolidate your JDBC code instead of having it scattered throughout the application is beneficial. Also should consider using a db connection pool. An example is Apache DBCP.  Just because it is a stand-alone app does not negate the benefit IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to it, I would :

- Create a dedicated library `dao.jar` (packaged as a jar) that would contain the DAO code
- Create a standalone (runable) application `app.jar` (runnable jar) that relies on this library
- Make my ear `app.ear` use the dedicated library (`dao.jar`) NOT the application

If there is some business logic, you can create an additional library that contains it `business.jar` that relies on `dao.jar` and make `app.jar` and `app.ear` rely on it too.

One jar should have only one major responsability or layer.

`dao.jar` can use any useful design principle or design pattern to access its data.